# Legend is disappearing on HighCharts pie refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Here is my code:

```
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        borderWidth: 3,
                        size: '90%',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Browser share',
                    data: [
                        ['item1',   35],
                        ['item2',       35],
                        ['item3',    30]
                    ]
                }]
            });

            $('.poll1 a').click(function() {
                $('.poll1 a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                chart.series[0].setData( [
                        ['item1',   75],
                        ['item2',       15],
                        ['item3',    10]
                    ]);
            });
        });
```

On click data in pie should be refreshed. It happens but the legend is disapearing. What I'm doing wrong? How can I leave legend in the same place?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and while it's not a great fix, I added false as the second parameter to setData (which makes it so it doesn't automatically redraw the chart), then manually redrew the chart.  So in your case:

```
chart.series[0].setData( [
    ['item1',   75],
    ['item2',       15],
    ['item3',    10]
], false);

chart.redraw();
```

That fixed it for me.